# R. Converting a vector of type character, into a string

Tags: r, string, vector, type-conversion, opennlp

I am having some trouble converting a vector type object into a string.

I have tried :

```
x <- paste(x, sep = " ", collapse = NULL)
```

and various different types of paste function but the return of `is.String(x)` is still `FALSE` and the return for `is.vector` is still `TRUE`. Here's my code below:

```
bio_sentences <- sent_detect(bio) #Using openNLP to get the sentences from a bio
is.vector(bio_sentences) #Returns TRUE
sentisimo <- bio_sentences[1] #Needed as I want to do analysis sentence by sentence
sentisimo <- paste(sentisimo, sep = " ", collapse = NULL)
as.character(sentisimo) 
is.vector(sentisimo) #Returns TRUE
is.character(sentisimo) #Returns TRUE
sentisimo <- paste(bio_sentences[1], sep = "")
as.String(sentisimo)
is.String(sentisimo) #Returns FALSE
str(sentisimo) Returns chr "1st sentence of the bio"
dput(sentisimo) #Returns "Dennis Muilenburg is chairman of the board, president and chief executive officer of The Boeing Company."
```

If anyone could help me convert the elements of a vector into a string I'd appreciate it.

Comment: from which library you got `is.String`

Comment: Please show the vector and your desired output.

Comment: @A. Suliman The package is called "NLP"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a string (as defined in the sense of the NLP package) is not the same as a base-R character.

```
library(NLP)
xchar <- "abc"
xstring <- as.String("abc")

> xchar
[1] "abc"
> xstring
abc
```

From this you can already see one of the differences of NLP stings and base R characters, namely the printing properties.
Also:

```
> is.character(xstring)
[1] TRUE
> is.String(xstring)
[1] TRUE
> is.character(xchar)
[1] TRUE
> is.String(xchar)
[1] FALSE
```

So if you want a String object you should use `as.String` instead of `as.character`

Comment: I have tried using as.String, yet I still get false once I try is.String

Comment: can you then give a complete example above so we can try and locate the problem? Also please give us the output of dput(sentisimo).

Comment: > dput(sentisimo)
"Dennis Muilenburg is chairman of the board, president and chief executive officer of The Boeing Company."

Comment: What do you mean by a complete example? I'm not sure what else I can add

Comment: you said you tried as.string(sentisimo), yet it does not show in your example.
Usually is.string(as.string(sentisimo)) should return TRUE.
Also your example cannot be reproduced since we need the function sent_detect.
Therefore you should provide dput(sentisimo)

Comment: Ah right that makes sense, apologies for that I'll edit it in, I commented it just before

Comment: as.string with an "a", not is.string:
try: sentisimo = as.String(sentisimo)
and then: is.String(sentisimo)

Comment: Yes I have tried as.String then is.String. The return is still FALSE

Comment: can you put this try in your example then.
Because in your question there is only the function is.String

Comment: ok; I am saying the same thing over and over but I think you are not understanding what I am saying.
Write: sentisimo = as.String(sentisimo) and then  is.String(sentisimo).
What you have written is: as.String(sentisimo) and then  is.String(sentisimo) which does not change the class of the object sentisimo.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Sorry for that I thought it was one and the same. I was sure I tried that but it works now!
Thank you so much and apologies for the brain fart I had